# Chrome - white space at the bottom of the website

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got a gap at the foot of my page - but only in Chrome. I've tried numerous things, mainly from this question & answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578963/white-space-at-bottom-of-site).

I'm pretty sure it's an overall body issue - I put a `border-bottom: 2px solid red;` rule on body and it came above the white space.

[image: foot of page - white space]

Here's my style code for body and footer -

```
body {

    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
    font-family: 'GothamLight', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;

}

footer {

  margin-top: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: black;
}


footer #email  {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
 /*  font-weight: bold; */
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: small;
}

  p #email {

  padding: 10px;

}

footer #socialmedia {

    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 75%;

}
```

Is there anything in there that might be causing it? As previously stated, there's no issue in Firefox and/or Safari - only Chrome. And it happens on all the pages of the site. How do I fix it?

Comment: What if you put margin-bottom:0; in body

Answer (score 1):

It look like padding problem , check for padding by changing , and check by removing position relative .   think it getting padding from any css file .

footer #socialmedia {

```
text-align: center;
position: relative;// remove it than check 
top: 75%;
```

}

Comment: That's got rid of the gap but now my social media icons won't stay where they were before because 'top' doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging on google and found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470715/css-white-space-at-bottom-of-page-despite-having-both-min-height-and-height-tag).

So now I just include `overflow: hidden;` in my **footer** style rules and it removes the white space.

Answer (score -1):

Use a cssclass in Social Media Div  and than call it in css and this way set your social media icons accordingly .

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: use a cssclass instead class or id ... i think u using ID. so replace it with cssclass='socialmedia "  and in css call it with like that .socialmedia

Comment: Sorry that's not working. I need a solution that solves the issue without disturbing the current code.